Podman Error Creating Container: [POST operation failed]
I have a podman container which has a python file to run a script that creates a container of a specific image_name and container_name.
Recreate the issue by folwing the below instaructions:
mkdir trial
cd trial

touch Dockerfile
touch create_container.py

Python File content:
from podman import PodmanClient
import sys

def create_container(image_name, container_name):
    with PodmanClient() as client:
        try:
            # Create and start the container
            container = client.containers.create(image=image_name, name=container_name)
            container.start()
            print(f"Container '{container_name}' created and started successfully.")
            print(f"Container ID: {container.id}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error creating container: {e}")
            sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        sys.exit(1)

    image_name = sys.argv[1]
    container_name = sys.argv[2]
    create_container(image_name, container_name)

DocekrFile:
FROM python:3.8.5-slim-buster
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the Python script into the container
COPY create_container.py .

# Install the Podman library
RUN pip install podman

# Set the entrypoint to run the Python script
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "create_container.py"]

Run :
podman build -t test
podman run --rm --privileged --network host -v /run/podman/podman.sock:/run/podman/podman.sock test <Name of the image> trial

Getting the Error:
Error creating container: http://%2Ftmp%2Fpodmanpy-runtime-dir-fallback-root%2Fpodman%2Fpodman.sock/v5.2.0/libpod/containers/create (POST operation failed)

My approach to solve the issue:
1)Thought that the Podmanclient is taking a random socket location, hence hardcoded the location when using Podmanclient in the python file.
...  
   with PodmanClient(uri='unix:///run/podman/podman.sock') as client:
  .
 .
.


was initially getting File permission issue at /run/podman/podman.sock hence chaged the ownership and file persmission for normal users.

3)Podman service would go inactive after a while hence changed the file at /usr/lib/systemd/system/podman.service to the below mentioned code:
[Unit]
Description=Podman API Service
Requires=podman.socket
After=podman.socket
Documentation=man:podman-system-service(1)
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=exec
KillMode=process
Environment=LOGGING="--log-level=info"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/podman $LOGGING system service tcp:0.0.0.0:8080 --time=0

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target

tried changing the tcp url to 127.0.0.1(loclhost) as well yet no success.

as a last resort i have uninstalled and reinstalled podman as well.
Note I am able to create a container outside using a python script with Podmanclient, so i think it must be a problem with podman and not the podman python package.

Thank you.
Code that runs outside the container. No change in the problem even if i add the extra os.environ in create_container.py file as well.
import os
import podman
# Set the Podman socket (adjust if necessary)
os.environ['PODMAN_SOCKET'] = '/run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock'

def create_container(image_name, container_name, command):
    try:
        print(f'Starting Container: {image_name}')
        print("Command running: " + command)

        client = podman.PodmanClient()  # Initialize Podman client

        # Use bind mount instead of named volume
        volume_src = '/home/vinee/myprojects/trial'  # Host directory
        volume_dst = '/edge/'  # Container mount point
        
        # Ensure the source path exists
        if not os.path.exists(volume_src):
            raise ValueError(f"Source volume path does not exist: {volume_src}")

        # Create the mount configuration
        bind_volumes = [
            {
                'type': 'bind',
                'source': volume_src,
                'target': volume_dst,
                'read_only': False  # Set to True if you want read-only access
            }
        ]

        # Create and start the container
        container = client.containers.run(
            image=image_name,
            name=container_name,
            command=command,
            detach=True,
            mounts=bind_volumes,  # Use the mounts configuration
            auto_remove=False,
            network_mode="host",
            shm_size=2147483648,
            privileged=True,
            devices=['/dev/nvidia0'],  # Specify device paths as needed
            environment={'TZ': 'Asia/Kolkata'}
        )

        print(f"Container ID: {container.id}")
        container_data = {
            'containername': container_name,
            'containerid': container.id,
            'imagename': image_name,
            'status': "RUNNING"
        }
        print("Container Information:")
        print(container_data)

        print("-" * 10 + " Container information updated successfully " + "-" * 10)
        print("Container Started Successfully")
        return {'message': 'Success'}

    except podman.errors.PodmanError as e:
        print(f"Podman specific error: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"General error creating container: {e}")
    return {'message': 'Error creating container'}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = create_container(
        "pythontest",
        "aA993dc42c504f4e853261105a2351bd",
        "python3 test.py"
    )
    print(result)


I didn't try messing with any permissons or unit-files but I had no problems using the container from your Dockerfile.
Are you sure you're not just missing the base_url argument?
I ran the newly built container test and mounted in the (rootless) podman socket.  I used PodmanClient interatively for a quick test:
$ podman run -it --rm --entrypoint='python3' --privileged \ 
-v /run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock:/run/podman/podman.sock test
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep 10 2020, 16:58:22)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from podman import PodmanClient
>>> with PodmanClient(base_url="http+unix:///run/podman/podman.sock") as client:
...    container = client.containers.run("busybox", ["sleep","infinity"],
...    detach=True, name="sleeper")
...
>>>

Exit python container and verify sleeper container creation:
$ podman ps --filter=name=sleeper
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                             COMMAND         CREATED         STATUS         PORTS       NAMES
c98f94c5c76f  docker.io/library/busybox:latest  sleep infinity  17 seconds ago  Up 17 seconds              sleeper
$

